# Way to use OPENXML function in SQL Server function?

Tags: sql-server, openxml

I need to use the `OPENXML` function in a SQL Server function, but stored procedures are not allowed in a function. As a result, I cannot use `sp_xml_preparedocument` to get the document handle, thus disabling me to use `OPENXML` function.

So my question is, is there any way that I can use `OPENXML` within a function **other than** turning my function into stored procedure?

Comment: Please show the code you are trying to run.

Comment: And see if [this answers your question](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1609/replacing-openxml-with-the-xml-nodes-function-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `OPENXML`. you can use nodes method over XML datatype and parse over the XML. [MSDN Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15)

> Scenarios for using the nodes() method are the same as for using
>   OPENXML (Transact-SQL), which provides a rowset view of the XML.
>   However, you don't have to use cursors when you use the nodes() method
>   on a table that contains several rows of XML documents.

```sql
DECLARE @location xml = '<root>  
  <Location LocationID="10">  
     <step>1</step>  
  </Location>  
  <Location LocationID="20">  
     <step>2</step>  
  </Location> 
  </root>'


CREATE FUNCTION ReturnStep (@location xml)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
SELECT t.value('.','int') as stepnumber
FROM @location.nodes('/root/Location/step') as loc(t)

SELECT * FROM dbo.ReturnStep(@location)
```

```
+------------+
| stepnumber |
+------------+
|          1 |
|          2 |
+------------+
```

Comment: @zening.chen, Glad to note that it was helpful

Comment: I still  have a question about xml-parsing in SQL Server, could you help out if convenient? Thank you! [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62401972/sql-server-error-xquery-nodes-a-node-or-set-of-nodes-is-required-for-node)

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openxml-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) you have to pass the `docId` to `OPENXML` which is an output parameter of `sp_xml_preparedocument`. Therefore there is a correlation with `OPENXML` and `sp_xml_preparedocument`.

Try this 
http://codegumbo.com/index.php/2013/09/30/sql-server-xquery-nodes-method/ 
https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/05/19/sql-server-handling-xml-documents-notes-field-125/

Comment: Answers need to be stand alone and **not** dependent on external links.